# MySQL Query - comparing string with set type

Tags: php, mysql, set

I have a column in my table of type `SET('alpha','beta','gamma','delta','...','omega')` and name 'alphabet'

My PHP query is

$string = "gamma"

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE alphabet LIKE "%$string%"
```

So I would like to return all of the rows where `gamma` is in the column `alphabet`, regardless of whar other values are in there too as it is a SET type.

What would the sql query be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set('$string', alphabet) > 0
```

[FIND_IN_SET Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)